# I want line break after slicing by \t pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do line break after slicing by \t. Could you possibly know about this?

| columns |
| --- |
| A00\t콜레라\tCholera |

=>

| columns |
| --- |
| A00 |
| 콜레라 |
| Cholera |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first `split` your column then `explode`:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.split("\t")
df.explode("column")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'columns':['A00\t콜레라\tCholera']})
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['columns'].str.split('\t').tolist()).stack()
new_df
```

Taken from [this Medium article](https://sureshssarda.medium.com/pandas-splitting-exploding-a-column-into-multiple-rows-b1b1d59ea12e)